# Creating a list from XML using Actionscript 3.0

Tags: xml, actionscript-3, list, xml-parsing

Here is my XML http://pastie.org/5413932

Basically I want to list the **names** of the **venues** in a list box using the list component in AS3! I have had many attempts at this without any luck.

I already have the code to load in the XML etc here http://pastie.org/5413941 
I have tried using **list.addItem({label:myXML.venue.name});** in a function which does list the names of the venues but for some reason I cannot select them one by one when I run the swf, I can only select the first one.

Im a newbie to AS3

Thanks in advance  :)

Comment: Are you using the Flex framework? Or just the standard Flash Pro components?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that you have asked about this xml a question lately - so as this time we can see the XML structure then:

```
var venueNames:XMLList = myXML.venue.name;//here you have all name's nodes
if(venueNames && venueNames.length() > 0)
{
    for each (var name:XML in venueNames) 
    {
        trace(name);

        list.addItem({label:name.toString()});
    }
}
```

this is how you register clicks on the items on the list:

```
list.addEventListener(ListEvent.ITEM_CLICK, nameSelectedHandler, false, 0, true);
```

this is what the event may contain:

```
[ListEvent type="itemClick" bubbles=false cancelable=true columnIndex=0 rowIndex=0 index=0 item=[object Object]]
```

the item property of that event is what ever object was placed through the addItem method, as you can see there is also index property - you could use it to identify which item was clicked. Then you can get the venue node from XML as follows:

```
myXml.venue[e.index];//where e is the ListEvent
```

you can wrap it with a function and than use it elsewhere like in the following example in handler for clicking on submit button:

```
    protected function onSubmit(e:MouseEvent):void
    {
        if(list.selectedIndex != -1)
        {
            trace(findVenueByIndex(list.selectedIndex));
        }
        else
        {
            trace("Nothing selected");
        }
    }

    protected function findVenueByIndex(index:int = 0):XML
    {
        return myXML.venue[index];
    }
```

regards

Comment: is it flex e.g. Flash Builder or Flash IDE e.g. Flash Professional CS6? How to do it can vary but in general if you can get what was clicked - and usualy you should be able with some kind of list view but you need something more to identify row than just a name - as it can be duplicated - there is also the data property you could use to add this identifier - but you have to read about it.

Comment: not realy you have to find venue node at index not description - I've updated my answer - also You have to read DOCUMENTATION I suggest to familiar yourself with [THIS](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/fl/controls/List.html) and [THAT](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/XML.html)

Comment: :) this was an example of trace "[ListEvent..." not part of the code. 
You are really new to programming - so please try with simple things first so you can learn about syntax, common problems/errors.

Comment: Hi, I've created [full example here](http://greladesign.com/temp/fl.controls.list%20and%20XML.zip) - analyse it, play with it and learn - bye

Comment: Thankyou very much I sorted the problem out once again thankyou for all your help!! :) I understand now where I went wrong...